# Remove trailing pipes - '|' in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
"PID||000000|Z123345|23345|SOMEONE^FIRSTNAME^^^MISS^||150|F|1111||1 DREYFUS CLOSE^SOUTH CITY^COUNTY^^POST CODE^^^||0123 45678910^PRN^PH^^^^0123 45678910^^~^^CP^^^^^^~^NET^^^^^^^||||1A|||||A||||||||N||||||||||";
```

I am trying to remove any separating '|' characters after the 30th '|' in the string so that the output string looks like this:

```
"PID||000000|Z123345|23345|SOMEONE^FIRSTNAME^^^MISS^||150|F|1111||1 DREYFUS CLOSE^SOUTH CITY^COUNTY^^POST CODE^^^||0123 45678910^PRN^PH^^^^0123 45678910^^~^^CP^^^^^^~^NET^^^^^^^||||1A|||||A||||||||N";
```

I am trying to do it using as little code as possible, but not having much luck.  Any help or ideas would be great.

Comment: "...after the 30th '|' in the string..." I would definitely look into substring, and for-loops (or while-loops). Those will help you out very much.

Comment: Assuming that this is pipe delimited, do you want the 31st + cells? Or just concatenate them into one cell?

Comment: Did you say 30th pipe because that happened to be the last one that wasn't a trailing pipe or is 30 an important part of the question? If there were fewer pipes before the N would there still remain trailing pipes? Would you remove pipes before the N if there were more than 30 before it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) method

```
string text = "stuff||||N||||||||||";
string result = text.TrimEnd('|'); //Result is stuff||||N
```

Comment: Not sure it matches exactly his requirements.

Comment: after 30 bars though?

Comment: "remove any separating '|' characters after the 30th '|' in the string" How does this exactly meet that requirement?

Comment: What if after the 29th bar there was no more 'normal' characters?

Comment: Or the field before the 30th is empty?

Comment: I admit the OP is pretty misleading. If instead of removing trailing pipes (like the title and example suggest) he really needs to remove the nth and following occurrences of a character, and that nth occurrence may happen before the last text segment, then yes Henk Holterman's answer would indeed be the optimal one.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force but only a little bit of code:

```
  string s2 = string.Join("|", s1.Split('|').Take(31));
```

If you need any other processing of this kind of data (it looks like a kind of nested CSV) then `string.Split()` is useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "PID||000000|Z123345|23345|SOMEONE^FIRSTNAME^^^MISS^||150|F|1111||1 DREYFUS CLOSE^SOUTH CITY^COUNTY^^POST CODE^^^||0123 45678910^PRN^PH^^^^0123 45678910^^~^^CP^^^^^^~^NET^^^^^^^||||1A|||||A||||||||N||||||||||";
int c = 0;
int after = 30;
StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0;i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] == '|'){
        if(after != c){
             newStr.append(str[i]);
             c++;
        }
    }else{
        newStr.append(str[i]);
    }
}
```

results in

```
newStr == "PID||000000|Z123345|23345|SOMEONE^FIRSTNAME^^^MISS^||150|F|1111||1 DREYFUS CLOSE^SOUTH CITY^COUNTY^^POST CODE^^^||0123 45678910^PRN^PH^^^^0123 45678910^^~^^CP^^^^^^~^NET^^^^^^^||||1A|||||A||||||||N";
```

Comment: You should be using a `StringBuilder` when doing such operation on strings.

Comment: I think it is one the best solution if the requirement is after 30 "|".

Comment: It wasn't incorrect before, it was just that your code used to create lots of temporary strings. Using the `StrinbBuilder` optimizes on that.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I haven't put it into a compiler or vs thats what I am saying xD

Comment: @MariusBancila - with less than 100 substrings a StringBuilder is not a very relevant optimization.

Answer (score 1):

If what you *really* want is that everything after the 30th chunk loses its '|', then try:

```
var chunks = input.Split('|');
var output = String.Join('|',chunks.Take(30)) + String.Concat(chunks.Skip(30));
```

That said, I think it sounds like what you're really looking for is probably something like:

```
var output = input.TrimEnd('|');
```

Comment: Instead of `Join` with empty separator you should use `String.Concat`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen good suggestion, updated my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

A regex should do the trick:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^([^\|]*\|){0,30}[^\|]*");
var match = regex.Match(input);
if(match.Success)
{
    var val = match.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the indexes of all the | characters.
int[] pipeIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length).Where(i => s[i] == '|').ToArray();

// If there are more than thirty pipes:
if (pipeIndexes.Length > 30)
{
    // The former part of the string remains intact.
    string formerPart = s.Substring(0, pipeIndexes[30]);

    // The latter part needs to have all | characters removed. 
    string latterPart = s.Substring(pipeIndexes[30]).Replace("|", "");

    s = formerPart + latterPart;
}
```